# Angular 6 Error Handler doesn't seem to be working

Tags: angular, error-handling

I'm trying to implement an error handler.

If i throw an error manually the handler works, but newer with server response errors.

Here is an implementation:

```
import {ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthenticationService} from './authentication.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  handleError(error: any): void {
    console.error('handleError()');
    const auth = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
      alert('Your session has expired');
      auth.logout();
    } else {
      alert('Error has occur. Message=' + error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

providers:

```
 providers: [

    AppErrorHandlerService,
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: AppErrorHandlerService
    }
  ]
```

Whenever i get 403 from server - it gets to console but not from custom error handler.

I'm not sure, but maybe it is related to requests interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const auth = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
    const authHeaders = auth.getAuthHeader();
    const authReq = request.clone({headers: authHeaders});

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Comment: try using `return next.handle(authReq).catch(err => this.AppErrorHandlerService.handleError(err));` in your interceptor